# GraphQL queries with tables join using Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, graphql

I am learning `GraphQL` so I built a little project. Let's say I have 2 models, `User` and `Comment`.

```
const Comment = Model.define('Comment', {
  content: {
    type: DataType.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
});

const User = Model.define('User', {
  name: {
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
  phone: DataType.STRING,
  picture: DataType.STRING,
});
```

The relations are `one-to-many`, where a user can have many comments.
I have built the schema like this:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    phone: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    comments: {
      type: new GraphQLList(CommentType),
      resolve: user => user.getComments()
    }
  })
});
```

And the query:

```
const user = {
  type: UserType,
  args: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    }
  },
  resolve(_, {id}) => User.findById(id)
};
```

Executing the query for a user and his comments is done with 1 request, like so:

```
{
  User(id:"1"){
    Comments{
      content
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand, the client will get the results using 1 query, this is the benefit using `GraphQL`. But the server will execute 2 queries, one for the user and another one for his comments.

My question is, what are the best practices for building the `GraphQL` schema and types and combining join between tables, so that the server could also execute the query with 1 request?

Answer (score 16):

The concept you are refering to is called batching. There are several libraries out there that offer this. For example:

- [Dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader): generic utility maintained by Facebook that provides "a consistent API over various backends and reduce requests to those backends via batching and caching"
- [join-monster](https://github.com/stems/join-monster): "A GraphQL-to-SQL query execution layer for batch data fetching."

Comment: If you prefer video, here is a talk about join monster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7AdMIuXOgs :)

Comment: Thank you for your post. Which one would you choose? On one hand I have facebook and 1800 stars library that batch some requests, but on the other hand I have a library that batch everything to 1 request.

Comment: We made good experiences with Dataloader at Graphcool, back when we were running a node GraphQL backend with graphql-js. Can't share any experience on join-monster. I think they slightly differ in features and usage so you would need to test it out I guess :)

Comment: Batching for me is something different! Batching means to take an array of IDs and (like in a 1 + N scenario) and get them all with one query. What join monster and [Photonjs](https://github.com/prisma/photonjs) do is something even better though, they leverage SQL joins to fulfil the GQL query with just a single SQL Query.

Answer (score 6):

To anyone using .NET and the [GraphQL for .NET](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) package, I have made an extension method that converts the GraphQL Query into Entity Framework Includes.

```
public static class ResolveFieldContextExtensions
{
    public static string GetIncludeString(this ResolveFieldContext<object> source)
    {
        return string.Join(',', GetIncludePaths(source.FieldAst));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Field> GetChildren(IHaveSelectionSet root)
    {
        return root.SelectionSet.Selections.Cast<Field>()
                                           .Where(x => x.SelectionSet.Selections.Any());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetIncludePaths(IHaveSelectionSet root)
    {
        var q = new Queue<Tuple<string, Field>>();
        foreach (var child in GetChildren(root))
            q.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, Field>(child.Name.ToPascalCase(), child));

        while (q.Any())
        {
            var node = q.Dequeue();
            var children = GetChildren(node.Item2).ToList();
            if (children.Any())
            {
                foreach (var child in children)
                    q.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, Field>
                                  (node.Item1 + "." + child.Name.ToPascalCase(), child));

            }
            else
            {
                yield return node.Item1;
            }
        }}}
```

Lets say we have the following query:

```
query {
  getHistory {
    id
    product {
      id
      category {
        id
        subCategory {
          id
        }
        subAnything {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We can create a variable in "resolve" method of the field:

```
var include = context.GetIncludeString();
```

which generates the following string:

```
"Product.Category.SubCategory,Product.Category.SubAnything"
```

and pass it to Entity Framework:

```
public Task<TEntity> Get(TKey id, string include)
{
    var query = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(include))
    {
        query = include.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Aggregate(query, (q, p) => q.Include(p));
    }
    return query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id.Equals(id));
}
```